# Can't update student data from StudentController update function

Tags: php, laravel-5

I tried to update student data from the database but I have got this error to update data. The error has given below:

***ERROR:***

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR) Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    //Insert data into Student Table
    $student = new Student;
    $student->name = $request->name;
    $student->registration_id = $request->registration_id;
    $student->department_name = $request->department_name;
    $student->info = $request->info;
    $student->save();

    return redirect()->route('index');   
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $student = Student::find($id);

    $student->name = $request->name;
    $student->registration_id = $request->registration_id;
    $student->department_name = $request->department_name;
    $student->info = $request->info;
    $student->save();

    return redirect()->route('index');
}[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: From your edit with the image, check your route - as it says, you're missing a parameter there.

Comment: `public function update(Request $request, $id)` You have not passed in the ID, check your routes, your method needs two arguments

Answer (score 1):

I already got my question's problematic solvency, the problem was I didn't keep ID inside the route function like ****Route::post('/update/{id}', 'StudentController@update')->name('update');****

Answer (score 0):

In your replace your form with

```
{!! Form::model($StudentEditData, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['student.update', $StudentEditData->id],'id'=>'myForm']) !!}
```